# how do I render my CSS to work well with Outlook

Tags: html, css, outlook

```
<tr>
    <td style="padding: 0 40px 40px; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 20px; color: #555555; text-align: left;">
        <p>Please invite <span style="display: inline; font-weight: bold;">Media Suite</span> to your meeting room. Please <span style="display: inline; font-weight: bold;">block</span> the video of the recorder.  Click the camera icon in the participants window on the left of the screen.  When scheduling, if it says that the resource is already scheduled you can click through to add it.</p>
        <div style="margin: 0 auto; margin-top: 89px; float: left; text-alight: bottom-center; width: 100px; height: 100px">
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/da/Microsoft_Excel_2013_logo_with_background.png" align="middle" style="border-radius: 25%; width: 90px; height: 90px;">
            <a href="https://sharepoint/file.xlsx" style="text-decoration: none; color: blue;" target="_blank">
                <span style="display: block; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; margin-top: 7px;" >meeting room checklist For Moderators</span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div style="margin: 0 auto; margin-top: 89px; float: right; text-alight: bottom-center; width: 100px; height: 100px">
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1a/Adobe_Reader_XI_icon.png" align="middle" style="border-radius: 25%; width: 90px; height: 90px;">
            <a href="https://sharepoint/file.pdf" style="text-decoration: none; color: blue; margin-top: 89px;" target="_blank">
                <span style="display: block; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; margin-top: 7px;" >How To Stream</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </td>                                
</tr>
```

This looks great in Chrome/IE and Edge but when Outlook renders it, it looks terrible. How can I style my CSS so it renders properly in email clients like Outlook, AirWatch Inbox or Boxer or other 3rd party html email clients

**Outlook Rendered Below**
[image: Outlook Render]

**Chrome Rendered Below**
[image: Chrome Render]

Comment: Emails are frustrating to develop.  Check out [campaignmonitor](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) for compat tables, and [litmus](https://litmus.com).

Comment: Thanks for the assist but I am actually not allowed to use 3rd party products to send emails.

Comment: Litmus doesn't send them, just checks in multiple clients.  If there's sensitive information, strip it out and replace with placeholder image/text to tweak the layout and replace content with yours before sending.

Answer (score 1):

Someone already gave you the answer and you ignored it.

- https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

As an example, you're not declaring your image width and Outlook is ignoring your inline styles. Outlook has limitations when it comes to div, margin, padding, styles, fonts and so much more.

Comment: I saw the CSS guide but there was a TON of stuff that had a red X. How would I position my two images and text without using margin, width, height (for Outlook 2016)

Comment: How would you? Welcome to email development. In the `<img>` you declare `width=90" height=90"` You're not doing that.